# c#, Problem with generic types

Tags: c#, generics

I have base class:

```
class ARBase<T> : ActiveRecordValidationBase<T> where T : class
{
}
```

and few child classes

```
class Producent : ARBase<Producent>
{
}

class Supplier : ARBase<Supplier>
{
}
```

Now in other class I want to have Property of type:

```
public IList<ARBase<Object>> MyCollection 
{
}
```

and want to be able to assign collection of Suppliers or collection of Producent, but I'm getting error: can't cast `List<Producent>` to `IList<ARBase<Object>>`...

Anyone know solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the problem is that .NET generics don't support covariance like this - there's support in certain cases, but only for interfaces and delegates, and C# only supports it as of version 4. (`IList<T>` still isn't variant in .NET 4.0 as it uses `T` in both an "in" and "out" sense.)

As an example of what could go wrong, imagine someone adding a `Supplier` to a list of `Producer`s - you wouldn't want that to be allowed, but it couldn't be prevented at compile-time if you could convert a `List<Producer>` to `IList<ARBase<object>>`.

What do you want your consumers to be able to do with your property? That will suggest how to proceed.

Comment: I'm trying to modify treegridview implementation (derived from ComponentFactory KryptonGridView) to support IList<T> as DataSource (currently only DataTable). And I want to pass to it IList<Producent> or IList<Supplier> and both are derived from ActiveRecordBase<T> class

Comment: If it's only for a `DataSource`, then you *could* just expose it as the nongeneric `IEnumerable`, couldn't you? It's leaves a bad taste in the mouth, but it will work.